# Passing data from service file to the component via Subject

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hey guys i am new in angular so i am trying to pass data from service File to the components via Subject but i see something weird .
For the first time when i go in the component i see nothing being displayed

Here is the screenshot of this
**https://ibb.co/3Ndw6QM**

there but after going in another compoenent and then adding a new data and coming back then i see all the data

Here is the screenshot again

**https://ibb.co/N30QHWy**

Below is the code

service file

```
export class PlacesService {

constructor(private aurservice:AuthService,
private router:Router) {      }

passallplaces = new Subject<any>();

places:Place[]=[
{
  title:'Manhattan mansion',
  description:'In the Heart of NYC',
  price:149.99,
  datefrom:new Date('2019-01-01'),
  dateto:new Date('2022-12-31'),
  id:'p1',

 image:'https://lonelyplanetimages.imgix.net/mastheads/GettyImages- 
 538096543_medium.jpg?sharp=10&vib=20&w=1200',
  userid:'abc'
},
{
  id:'p2',
  title:'L\'Amour Toujours',
  description:'Romantic place in Paris',
  image:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/
  thumb/e/e6/Paris_Night.jpg/1024px-Paris_Night.jpg',
  price:189.99,
  datefrom:new Date('2019-01-01'),
  dateto:new Date('2019-12-31'),
  userid:'abc'
},
{
  id:'p3',
  title:'The Foggy palace',
  description:'Not your average city trip',
  image:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/
  commons/0/01/San_Francisco_with_two_bridges_and_the_fog.jpg',
  price:99.99,
  datefrom:new Date('2019-01-01'),
  dateto:new Date('2019-12-31'),
  userid:'abc'
}
]

addplace(title:string,description:string,price:number,
from:Date,to:Date){

const newplace=new Place(title,description,
price,from,to,Math.random().toString(),
' https://lonelyplanetimages.imgix.net/mastheads/GettyImages- 
538096543_medium.jpg?sharp=10&vib=20&w=1200',
this.aurservice.userid);

this.places.push(newplace)
this.passallplaces.next(this.places)
}

}
```

component.ts

```
offers:Place[]
subscription:Subscription
constructor(private menuctrl:MenuController,private  
router:Router,private plservice:PlacesService) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.subscription=this.plservice.passallplaces.subscribe(p=>{
  this.offers=p
  console.log(p)

})



}



ngOnDestroy(){
this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

html file

```
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-buttons slot="start" >
  <ion-button (click)="onmenu()">
  <ion-icon name="menu" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>
  </ion-buttons>
<ion-title>My Offers</ion-title>
<ion-buttons slot="end" (click)="onplus()">
    <ion-button> 
     <ion-icon name="add" slot="icon-only" ></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-buttons>

</ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let offer of offers">
   <ion-thumbnail slot="start">   
   <img [src]="offer.image">

  </ion-thumbnail>

      <ion-label>
        <h2>{{offer.title}}</h2>
        <div class="offer-details">
          <ion-icon name="calendar" class="space-left"></ion-icon>
         <ion-text class="space-left"> {{offer.datefrom|date}} . 
  </ion-text>
        <ion-text class="space-left">
          to
        </ion-text >
          <ion-icon name="calendar" class="space-left"></ion-icon>
        <ion-text class="space-left">
          {{offer.dateto|date}} 
        </ion-text>

        </div>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>

   </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Subject, and a Subject has no starting value, so there will be no value coming to your component. I suggest that you use a BehaviorSubject instead, the BeahviorSubject can take in a starting value, so something like this:

```
passallplaces = new BehaviorSubject<any>(places);
```

Comment: This doesn't fully address the question being asked. The reason there is no data is because your subject has already fired the event before your component initialized. Also you should utilize types here.

Comment: Are you sure about that @Nanotron? I can't see any place in the code that a event is passed / nexted to the subject in the initialization, so I don't think the Subject has received any value at all.

Comment: Yes I think so @SnorreDan - in the constructor of his service.

Comment: @Nanotron I can't see anything going on in the constructor of his service, just an empty "{ }"

Comment: yes it appears I am mistaken. seems weird he was expecting data when he never sent any